# Checkbox refusing to disable form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, requirejs

Very new at this so bear with me!

I'm attempting to create a checkbox function which disables the form input when toggled off. This is what my code looks like:

```
'use strict';
define('admin/settings/post', ['admin/settings'], function () {
var Module = {
};

Module.init = function () {
    console.log('test');
    $('[data-field="toggleUserRestrictions"]').on('click', function() {
        if $('[data-field="toggleUserRestrictions"]').attr('checked') {
            $('input[data-type="newUserRestrictions"]').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('input[data-type="newUserRestrictions"]').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
};

return Module;
});
```

Is there anything blatantly wrong with this code that I'm failing to see?

Comment: use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: ^ `$('[data-field="toggleUserRestrictions"]').prop('checked')`

Comment: Would you show your html code?

Comment: Check this:- https://prnt.sc/h83ki7